# Write each list as a column in csv table

Tags: python, csv, writer

I have multiple lists with each list containing strings that I want to fill in a csv table. I want each list to be a separate column of data in its respective column header. The header row is the same sequence as the outrow variable. With the code below it simply just fills in the first column with all the data from all the lists.

```
#outrow = (Layer,RasterCatalog,ShapeFile,Text,Terrain,GroupLayer,Locator,MapDocument,Toolbox,DbaseTable,RasterDataset)

#formats = (['Layer','RasterCatalog','ShapeFile','Text','Terrain','GroupLayer','Locator','MapDocument','Toolbox','DbaseTable','RasterDataset'])

# if I were to print(outrow), it would look like this:
   #(['H:\\Test\\Test_Data\\New Layer.lyr'], [], ['H:\\Test\\Test_Data\\New_Shapefile.dbf', 'H:\\Test\\Test_Data\\New_Shapefile.shp'], [], [], [], [], [], [], ['H:\\Test\\Test_Data\\New_dBASE_Table.dbf'], [])

def WriteCSVFile(csvFile,formats,outrow):

    ofile  = open(csvFile, "wb")        
    writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(formats) #making header here
    writer.writerows(outrow)
    ofile.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then `outrow` is a list of lists, where each list contains one column, right? Then (assuming that they are all of the same length) you can simply `zip()` them together:

```
writer.writerows(zip(*outrow))
```

To illustrate:

```
>>> outrow = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
>>> import csv
>>> import sys
>>> w = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
>>> w.writerows(zip(*outrow))
1,4,7
2,5,8
3,6,9
```

If the columns are of different length, use `izip_longest()` from the [`itertools` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) (`zip_longest()` if you're on Python 3):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> outrow = (['H:\\Test\\Test_Data\\New Layer.lyr'], [], ['H:\\Test\\Test_Data\\New_Shapefile.dbf', 'H:\\Test\\Test_Data\\New_Shapefile.shp'], [], [], [], [], [], [], ['H:\\Test\\Test_Data\\New_dBASE_Table.dbf'], [])
>>> w.writerows(itertools.izip_longest(*outrow, fillvalue=""))
H:\Test\Test_Data\New Layer.lyr,,H:\Test\Test_Data\New_Shapefile.dbf,,,,,,,H:\Test\Test_Data\New_dBASE_Table.dbf,,,H:\Test\Test_Data\New_Shapefile.shp,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: each list is different lengths

Comment: @wannabe_n00b: OK, and what should be put into the column after the list is empty? Perhaps you could show some example input and desired output. I may not have understood your question correctly.

Comment: Sure, I added some more info. I basically want each list to print vertically down the column.